# How to find out elements from AVD in a frame using Ui AutoViewer?

Tags: android, selenium, appium, android-uiautomator

[image]

Just the marked red line came. But inner side elements are not recognized.
Please guide me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Feels this is a WebView. Elements inside might not be visible to UIAutomator.

Answer (score 0):

Ui Autoviewer is not good tool for that tbh.
Best option is to

1. switch context to web view
2. print to console page source (in c# `Console.WriteLine(_driver.PageSource);`)

Comment: How to switch to web view and print the page source.